# Solr SpellChecking suggestions

Tags: solr, spell-checking

When I use the "spellcheck" in Solr I have always 1 result even if it should be more. For example if I have the word "conjecture" and I search "conjicture" I will find it, the same thing if I have the word "conjoncture" but if I have the two words (conjecture and conjoncture) I will have only one result.
Currently, I'm using this :

```
searchComponent name="spellcheck" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">
    <str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">text_spell</str>
    <lst name="spellchecker">
      <str name="name">default</str>
      <str name="field">copie_content</str> 
      <str name="classname">solr.DirectSolrSpellChecker</str> 
      <str name="distanceMeasure">internal</str> 
      <float name="accuracy">0.5</float>
      <int name="maxEdits">2</int>
      <int name="minPrefix">0</int>
      <int name="maxInspections">10</int>
      <int name="minQueryLength">4</int>
      <float name="maxQueryFrequency">0.01</float>
      <str name="spellcheck.maxResultsForSuggest">5</str>
    </lst>
  </searchComponent>
```

Comment: Please expand your question with proper examples - do you mean that you only get one suggestion for two misspelled words, or do you only get one suggestion even if two words could be the ones correctly spelled? What parameters are you using? (the edit distance is larger on `conjoncture` than for `conjecture`)

Comment: @MatsLindh I have only one suggestion even if two words could be the ones correctly spelled. But, if I have only one of the two words in my index (conjecture and conjoncture) I will find it with searching("conjicture")